# Windows Media Encoder - Audio Codecs

Tags: audio, codec, windows-media-encoder

When encoding and streaming audio with Windows Media Encoder 9 (with WMA 10 Professional codecs installed), there seems to be a minimum audio latency of ~2 seconds, even when using the Low Delay CBR configurations.

Are there any codecs out there that can be installed into Windows Media Encoder and that would encode to mp4a with a reduced latency?  Or are there other WME settings that can be changed to accomplish this?  VLC seems to be able to encode to mp4a with a 1.5 sec delay.

Comment: It would be best beneficial to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you have so far to avoid the community doing any heavy lifting.